# Wrong display depending on displayed bitmap size

Tags: mfc

I am having a trouble in a SDI view.
I am using the following code to display a bitmap buffer. 
Depending on the width of the bitmap and when the width is becoming large, then a flickering problem occurs.
Additionally, the view is displaying weird data as seen below :

[image: Flickering and weird display]

Here is the expected display.
[image: Correct display]

The code I am using for this view is here :

```
void CTestLargeView::RefreshDisplay()
{
    CClientDC dc(this);
    CRect cRect;
    GetClientRect(&cRect);

    LPBITMAPINFO pBmpInfo;
    pBmpInfo = (LPBITMAPINFO) new BYTE[sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER) + 256 * sizeof(RGBQUAD)];

    pBmpInfo->bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    pBmpInfo->bmiHeader.biWidth = XSize;
    pBmpInfo->bmiHeader.biHeight = YSize;
    pBmpInfo->bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
    pBmpInfo->bmiHeader.biBitCount = 32;
    pBmpInfo->bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
    pBmpInfo->bmiHeader.biSizeImage = XSize * YSize;
    pBmpInfo->bmiHeader.biXPelsPerMeter = 0;
    pBmpInfo->bmiHeader.biYPelsPerMeter = 0;
    pBmpInfo->bmiHeader.biClrUsed = 0;
    pBmpInfo->bmiHeader.biClrImportant = 0;

    SetStretchBltMode(dc.m_hDC, STRETCH_DELETESCANS);
    StretchDIBits(dc.m_hDC, 
                  0, 
                  0, 
                  cRect.Width(), 
                  cRect.Height(), 
                  0, 
                  0, 
                  XSize, 
                  YSize, 
                  Data, 
                  pBmpInfo, 
                  DIB_RGB_COLORS, 
                  SRCCOPY);

    delete[] pBmpInfo;
}

void CTestLargeView::OnTimer(UINT_PTR nIDEvent)
{
    if (nIDEvent == 150)
        RefreshDisplay();

    CView::OnTimer(nIDEvent);
}

int CTestLargeView::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct)
{
    if (CView::OnCreate(lpCreateStruct) == -1)
        return -1;

    SetTimer(150, 33, NULL);

    XSize = 32000;  // No flickering
    //XSize = 32800;    // Flickering occurring

    YSize = 256;

    Data = new int[XSize * YSize];

    for (int i = 0 ; i < XSize * YSize ; i++)
        Data[i] = RGB(i % 255, i % 255, i % 255);

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks !

Comment: I can't see where you are initialising the colour table of pBmpInfo. Also you have allocated space for a 256 colour table and then specified the number of colours used to be zero. Also you ought to be doing your screen updates in CView::OnDraw() using the dc you get given.

Comment: Also, `biSizeImage` is wrong, it should be the size in bytes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem->
It is caused by the "STRETCH_DELETESCANS". Changing it to STRETCH_HALFTONE is correcting the trouble.